# Removing AdMob from app in Android Studio

Tags: android, admob, android-gradle-plugin

Google is now demanding that publishers identify apps with ads. Fine, my game has no ads so I went to select no, but the developer console says they have detected AdMob SDK 11 in my app. The thing is I'm sure my game doesn't have AdMob. It's never shown ads, AdMob is not in the manifest and I can't seem to find it anyplace else. How can I make sure?

Comment: How are you using Google Play Services? Are you including only the things that you need and not everything (which would include AdMob). https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. For some reason Google Play services is in dependencies and it apparently includes AdMob. I'll just remove it and see if the console wises up. Maybe you should put this as an answer, in case there's a deluge of similar questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are including Google Play Services in your build.gradle file just make sure you are including only the things that you need as it contains many features, such as Google Maps, Google Fit, Google Advertising, etc. For more details see:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

**EDIT**

In any library or framework you are using that pulls in Google Play Services you should know what it is being used for and if you don't reach out to the source and ask.

For starters use the Google Actions Base Client Library:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:x.x.x
```

And then add in which Play Services feature libraries you need.

Comment: Any idea what services a basic app needs? Because after removing google play services, I get a lot of errors, import android.graphics is not recognized anymore for example.

Comment: Found it, it's: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:x.x.x`