# Google Play: We found Ad SDKs in your application

Tags: android, google-play

Google has put a new option on their Pricing and Distribution page of their Google Play Developer Console that requires publishers to declare if they have ads or not. Our app does not have ads, yet we are being flagged as having the AdMob SDK.

> We detected Ad SDKs in one or more of your active APKs:
>
> ```
> version: XXXXX, sdk: AdMob
> ```
>
> If your app is serving ads, please change your ads declaration to
>   'Yes'. Failure to accurately declare the presence of ads is a policy
>   violation and may result in your app's removal from Google Play. You
>   can visit our Help Center to learn more.

We don't have AdMob, as far as I can tell from our Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

What might be causing that dependency to show up? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788247/removing-admob-from-app-in-android-studio

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can run `gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies` to see a the dependencies (including all transitive dependencies) for each of your configurations.

You can also specify a single configuration, such as with `--configuration releaseCompile`

In your case, you will find that Google Play Services includes a transitive dependency on AdMob.

You can mitigate this by using [only individual components of Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) (such as `play-services-location`) instead of the entirety of Play Services. However, you may find that one of the individual components you use still relies on AdMob. For example, version 8.1.0 of `play-services-analytics` has a transitive dependency on `play-services-ads`, which is the AdMob SDK.

Comment: It was coming from the `com.google.android.gms:play-services:x.x.x` dependency. By changing that to just maps `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:x.x.x` I was able to get rid of that AdMob dependency. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `play-services-analytics` dependency upon `play-services-ads` seems to be limited to version 8.1.0. Previous and later versions of `play-services-analytics` no longer have this transitive dependency, unless I am misreading the POMs somehow... Other than that, though, great analysis!

Comment: @CommonsWare you are correct! I hadn't had a chance to update Google Play Services recently, but doing so removed the transitive dependency.

Comment: Ads identifier is also included in firebase analytics:
``com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0`` contains 
``com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.0`` which contains
``com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0``

Comment: Authentic source from Google claiming this in first stmt https://firebase.google.com/policies/analytics

Answer (score 24):

I have follow below steps and It removes the notification

First check that which gradle package contains "play-services-ads-identifier" package depency. You can add update those packages like below:

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement-sdk"
}
```

Second, If you have analytics package in your gradle which contains ads then you have to follow these steps OR you can skip it. You can add below tag in your app's manifest's  tag.

```
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />
```

Hope it will help you as well.

Comment: I have these two 
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0" sdks being used in my app and I am getting the same issue.

Comment: To solve this issues accurately, Here are the steps:
1. Find a list of dependacy which contains "play-services-ads-identifier". You can follow steps from below URL
https://medium.com/android-news/gradle-dependency-tree-819b68898a53
2. Now, You have a list of dependacy who contains "play-services-ads-identifier", so add {    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier" } in each dependacy to remove.
3. After following steps 2, You need to execute steps 1 again to verify that, Once you found that  "play-services-ads-identifier" is removed. You can good to upload app on Play store.

Comment: implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics') {
        exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
        exclude module: "play-services-measurement"
        exclude module: "play-services-measurement-sdk"
    }

Here is another updates to exclude ads from measurements as well.

Answer (score 11):

From the Google Play Support Chat I was addressed to say "No" in Google Play Console, despite the detection.

Comment: I have also had this detection and I make no use of advertising SDK. I have just selected the no option.

Comment: Same. I selected the no option and Google Play did not remove my app.

Comment: Did you have any consequence for doing this?

Comment: This is not a solution, you can say "No" and your app will be  deleted, you must be sure of not having dependencies or code related to AdMob.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved with these steps

1. First find list of android dependencies which contain `play-services-ads-identifier`. Through Android Studio Gradle Panel
   [Click on Gradle tab on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tj1o.png)

[Task will print all dependencies including internal packages example included in below image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ye0u.png)

2. After that exclude `play-services-ads-identifier`. in my case I have two dependencies which contain `play-services-ads`.

- First dependency:

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.2') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement-sdk"
}
```

- Second dependency:

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics') {
    exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement"
    exclude module: "play-services-measurement-sdk"
}
```

It solved my issues.

Comment: Does it affect firebase analytics as well ? I need to keep analytics but just remove AD_ID permission...

Comment: I did the same thing and it removed the ads-identifier library. However I am not sure if there are going to be any runtime crashes. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: On my side, I had to also remove `play-services-measurement-api`