# Is there a way to avoid including Google Ads libraries from gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have been publishing two flavors for an Android app in Google Play Console, one for the free version (ads) and another for the pro version (ads-free). Both flavors include the Ads SDK, but in the pro version banners are not loaded according to the packagename.

Due to the new [Google's Ads-label policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?rd=1#ads) developers must identify whether theirs apps use Ads. I specified for my pro version that I don't use Ads, but Google Play Console detects the Ads SDK: We found Ad SDKs in your application

So, is there a way to avoid including Google Ads libraries from gradle?

Here is my gradle definition for my app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 22

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.lgallardo.qbittorrentclient'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        archivesBaseName = "qBittorrentClient_v" + versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }


    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    adbOptions {
        timeOutInMs 600000
    }
    productFlavors {
        pro {
            applicationId 'com.lgallardo.qbittorrentclientpro'
            versionName '4.2.4'
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 424
            archivesBaseName = "qBittorrentController_v" + versionName
        }
        free {
            applicationId "com.lgallardo.qbittorrentclient"
            versionName '4.2.4'
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 424
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    // Robotium
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.4.1'
    }
}
```

Despite [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788471/google-play-we-found-ad-sdks-in-your-application), my free app does use Ads, but I don't want to include Google Play Services libraries in the pro version, using Gradle flavors, therefore is not a duplicated question.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, it's not the same questions. The other one does not use Ads. My app does use it, but I want to avoid including Google Play Services in the pro version, using Gradle flavors!

Comment: From the Google Play Support Chat I was addressed to say "No" in Google Play Console, despite the detection.