# False positive for AdMob detection by GooglePlay

Tags: google-play, admob, google-play-console

In `Google Play Console`, under `AppContent`, we found a warning under `Ads` section stating:

```
We found ad SDKs in your app
```

Although we still can publish our app for now, this warning is bothering us.

It does not allow us to declare `No, my app does not contain ads`. The `save` button is greyed out.

**The problem is, we did not integrate AdMob in our app!** So what could trigger this false positive?

I have ran `gradlew -q app:dependencies` and extracted out our `productionRelease` section. A copy of the full dependency list can be found here: http://axzae.com/dependency.txt

The only "ads" related dependency we found is:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:{strictly 17.0.0} -> 17.0.0 (c)
```

But we are just using adid as a unique identifier for identifying user. Could this be the false positive reason?

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if play store finds that you are displaying advertisements. It shows this message "App contains ads". If you want to have it removed, recommend to switch to firebase analytics based identifier.

Comment: Having the same problem, Google detects AdMob but we can't find a trace of it in our builds. We found however the same package as you "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0" that comes with the base package of Firebase

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788471/google-play-we-found-ad-sdks-in-your-application

Answer (score 0):

If you or one of the libraries in your app are using Identifier for Advertisers (IDFA), Google play will tell you `We found ad SDKs in your app`

But if you are not showing ads do not worry about it, in this case it is indeed a false positive and Google know that and tell you to leave it as is (*see the image below*)

[image]

It is just for Google Play to check if you lied about the ads in your app, so they can later remove your app.

I found that some analytics SDKs uses this technique to identify unique users more efficiently.

for example [OneSignal SDK](https://onesignal.com/) uses this.