# Google play: We found ad SDKs in your app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have this warning in the google play console, which tells me that I have ads in the app, but I did not use any ads in my app.

> Ads
> Let us know whether your app contains ads. This includes ads
> delivered by third party ad networks. Make sure this information is
> accurate and is kept up to date. Learn more
>
> We found ad SDKs in your app

This is Gradle dependencies, I did not know which library uses ads dependency, How I should know?

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {

    }

    implementation files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'){
        exclude group: "com.android.volley"
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:5.1'
    implementation'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:7.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.5'
    implementation 'net.objecthunter:exp4j:0.4.7'
    implementation ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.10'){
        force = true
    }
    implementation 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:3.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.alxrm:audiowave-progressbar:0.8'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.5.1'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.asksira.android:webviewsuite:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.3'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
    implementation 'moe.feng:MaterialStepperView:0.2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.github.danielceinos:Cooper:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.5.3-beta3'
    implementation 'cards.pay:paycardsrecognizer:1.1.0'

    // Payments gateways SDK
    implementation 'com.eway.payment:android-sdk:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.sdk:point-of-sale-sdk:2.0'
    implementation 'net.authorize:accept-sdk-android:1.0.2'
    implementation(name: 'wepay-android-3.0.0', ext: 'aar')

    //Location Library
    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.tomergoldst.android:tooltips:1.0.10'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
}
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play: We found Ad SDKs in your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788471/google-play-we-found-ad-sdks-in-your-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ads dependencies come from firebase, exclude ads dependence from firebase

```
exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module : 'play-services-ads-identifier'

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module : 'play-services-ads-identifier'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module : 'play-services-ads-identifier'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module : 'play-services-ads-identifier'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module : 'play-services-ads-identifier'
    }

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.4.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module : 'play-services-ads-identifier'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.3'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module : 'play-services-ads-identifier'
    }
```